Cannot install NextJS on Ubuntu Terminal
This happens when I install the node and npm are on the latest version.
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:818
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'stream/promises'
Require stack:
- /home/julius/.npm/_npx/cc2145a2fe1558fa/node_modules/create-next-app/dist/index.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:815:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:667:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:887:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:85:18)
    at Module.8776 (/home/julius/.npm/_npx/cc2145a2fe1558fa/node_modules/create-next-app/dist/index.js:74:30476)
    at __nccwpck_require__ (/home/julius/.npm/_npx/cc2145a2fe1558fa/node_modules/create-next-app/dist/index.js:74:59347)
    at /home/julius/.npm/_npx/cc2145a2fe1558fa/node_modules/create-next-app/dist/index.js:74:60211
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/julius/.npm/_npx/cc2145a2fe1558fa/node_modules/create-next-app/dist/index.js:74:60255)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:999:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:10) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    '/home/julius/.npm/_npx/cc2145a2fe1558fa/node_modules/create-next-app/dist/index.js'
  ]
}

I need help to fix installing nextJS on ubuntu terminal
